# Activity is blank when starting new Activity from tab in Android

Tags: android

I have encountered a problem in my Android application.  It is a currency converter app.  When I start a new activity from a tab, the activity is blank.  Here is part of my MainActivity.java code:

```
    package com.example.currencyconverter;

    import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ProgressDialog progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
EditText edittextdollars;
EditText edittexteuros;
TextView dollars;
TextView euros;
RadioButton dtoe;
RadioButton etod;
RadioGroup radiogroup;
Spinner spinner1;
Spinner spinner2;
Button calculate;
String[] tabTitle = {"Converter", "Currencies", "News"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle("Created By Rohit Nandakumar");
    actionBar.setTitle("Currency Converter"); 
    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            String n = tab.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (n.equals("Converter")) {
                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));  
                } 
            if (n.equals("Currencies")) {
                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class)); 
                }
            if (n.equals("News")) {
                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class)); 
                }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(tabTitle[i])
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }




}


private void addListenerOnButton() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    edittextdollars = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextdollars);
    edittexteuros = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittexteuros);

}

public interface CurrencyConverter {
    public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws Exception;
}

public class YahooCurrencyConverter implements CurrencyConverter{
     public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws IOException {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + currencyFrom + currencyTo + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
            //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDEUR=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            return Double.parseDouble(responseBody);
}


}



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("USD","EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("EUR","USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("EUR","USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("USD","EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertEurostoEuros();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            OppositeOfConvertEurostoEuros();
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertDollarstoDollars();
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            OppositeOfConvertDollarstoDollars();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertEurostoEuros();
        }          
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            OppositeOfConvertDollarstoDollars();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("INR","USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("USD","INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("INR","EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("EUR","INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("USD","INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("INR","USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("INR","EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("EUR","INR");
        }



        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("JPY","JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY","JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("JPY","USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("USD","JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("JPY","INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("INR","JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("JPY","EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("EUR","JPY");
        }



        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("USD","JPY");
        } 
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY","USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("EUR","JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY","EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            convertvalues("INR","JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length()==0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY","INR");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        progressBar.hide();
    }



/* public void convertDollarstoEuros() {
    double current;
    double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
     YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();
     //current = ycc.convert("USD", "EUR");

    //edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
     //edittexteuros.setText(df.format(6));

         try {
            current = ycc.convert("USD", "EUR");
            //System.out.println(current);
            edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            //return errors.toString();
        }
        //    e.printStackTrace();
            //edittexteuros.setText(df.format(6));
        } 


         public String convertDollarstoEuro1() {
            double current;
            double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
             YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();
              //current = ycc.convert("USD", "EUR");

            //edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
             //edittexteuros.setText(df.format(6));

                 try {
                    current = ycc.convert("USD", "EUR");
                    //System.out.println(current);
                    edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
                    return "passed";
                    }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                    return errors.toString();
                //    e.printStackTrace();
                    //edittexteuros.setText(df.format(6));
                } 
         }
         */

                public String convertvalues(String convertfrom, String convertto) {
                    double current;
                    double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
                     YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();                  
                         try {
                            current = ycc.convert(convertfrom, convertto);
                            edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
                            return "passed";
                            }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                            return errors.toString();
                        } 
    }
                public String convertvalues2(String convertfrom2, String convertto2) {
                    double current;
                    double val=Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
                     YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();                  
                         try {
                            current = ycc.convert(convertfrom2, convertto2);
                            edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val*current)); 
                            return "passed";
                            }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                            return errors.toString();
                        } 

                }


}
```

This is my AndroidManifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.currencyconverter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:smallScreens="true"
                android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.currencyconverter.FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.currencyconverter.OtherMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_other_main" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have all the activities named too.  What happened?  Why isn't my app working?  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In each activity are you loading the view? Basically are you calling this: setContentView(R.layout.xxx)

Comment: +1 to what JamesBlack said. You need to show us your onCreate method in FirstActivity.java

Comment: Yes, I am. (to James Black question)  I will post the whole code up.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: @mattgmg1990 I have posted my code.

Comment: @JamesBlack I have posted my code.

Comment: @user2507301 I wanted to see your code for FirstActivity.java. In two of the tabs you use this line to start FirstActivity: `startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class)); `, I think that the error will be there. This is assuming that starting an entirely new activity is really what you want to do. It seems to me that you may be doing the wrong thing here and probably want to display a fragment in the space for the tab. However, that would be another question entirely if that is the case...

Answer (score 1):

plaese use this code or set layout file for new view.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
```

ft.replace(R.id.layoutfile, fragment);
}

Comment: it's usefull than give me 1+

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  What should I do?

Comment: are you use tab in action bar or not?

Comment: use this link for reference http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/create-actionbar-in-tab-navigation-mode.html